# ASP.NET MVC Applicatoin - Downgrading Oracle client version

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracleclient

facing a problem here. We developed an asp.net mvc 4 app on a dev environment which has the oracle client v12.1 and the test environment using v 11.2 I believe.

When we deploy the app to test we receive this error
[image: error]

We're unable to install the later version on the test environment, so the question is, is there as a simple way to downgrade the dev environment back to v11.2 and what main changes would I have to make on the .NET side, would there just be some assembly reference changes etc? I dont think there's any new features of ODP.NET that wouldnt be compatible with v11.2

This is the first encounter with Oracle I've ever had, so apologies if some of this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a Binding Redirect on web.config? There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092928/assembly-binding-redirect-to-a-lower-version) and you can find MSDN doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could add it to the test environment web.config to redirect all references that use version 12 to use version 11, but I would only use it as a temporary fix. You should either upgrade the test environment or downgrade the dev one, and those should match the prod environment to avoid unexpected issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give the binding redirect a go. In regards to downgrading the dev environment. How simple is this? Sorry to ask but I'm new to all this. Would downgrading the client version and then re-compiling work?

Comment: For downgrading, you need to have installed in that environment the old version and update the reference in your project to point to that version. Normally, you can verify the referenced version easily from the Object Browser in Visual Studio (just expand the references list, right click on the reference and choose View in Object Browser).

Comment: I tried the binding redirect like you said              
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.1.0" newVersion="4.112.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>                The Oracle.DataLayer.dll within the inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\bin is at v4.121.10, and the dll within C:\oracle\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4 is v4.112.2.0.  Yet im now getting an error saying TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: I haven't used the Oracle drivers in a while, but looking here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12150.htm seems that it's an issue with the connection string. Are you using something in the connection string that is only supported in the new version of the driver?