# Error could not load type ...Maxlength

Tags: c#, mtm, testrail

I am making an application for migration working with Microsoft test manager and i have that exception

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.MaxLength' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

i added the right reference but still got that error 
can anyone help me please

Comment: Check if this assembly is in GAC (C -> Windows -> assemblies or use gacutil.exe). If it is not then check if it is copied to bin/Debug directory. You may want to set Copy True on assembly reference properties (just click on reference and navig to properties window).

Comment: I check in my c->windows-> assembly and i the assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common, Version=10.0.0.0,  so as you can see it is not the same version that i got in my reference.

Comment: when you say bin/debug directory you talking about my the folder generated in my visual studio project after the build thing ?

Comment: Exactly bin/Debug in your project directory

Comment: also set copy true  the reference properties for  assembly.

Comment: But was this DLL in bin/Debug directory? And if it was, were version equal 14.0.0.0?

Comment: I have done what you say but it's not work yet

Comment: You still don't *write* in the comments if DLL was in Debug directory, if you answer this question it will help me know what may be wrong...

Comment: The simple solution will be to downgrade to version 10.0.0.0 by changing referenced assembly in your project. Other solution is to use rebinding to load older version described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092928/assembly-binding-redirect-to-a-lower-version The last but the best solution is to find version 14 and install it in GAC or deploy it with your application

Comment: Yup!  this dll  is  in bin/Debug  directory  and the version equal 14.0.0.0

Comment: i can't downgrade to version 10.0.0.0 because my constructor use that version and if i do that i got another error there.

Comment: how can i do the last solution you suggested ? where can i find the version 14 and how install it in GAC or deploy it with your applicatio?

Comment: OK, I see if DLL is in `bin/Debug` system should load it. So the problem may be that this `MaxLenght` type was removed in newer version. You may use ILSpy or other decompiler to load `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common` and check if `MaxLength` is declared in that DLL.

Comment: Look at these 2 MSDN pages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.common(v=vs.100).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.common(v=vs.140).aspx looks like MaxLength class was removed after release of Visual Studio 2012

Comment: you're right! do you think it is a good idea to add that class to the version 14.0.0.0

Comment: You cannot do that, this assembly is part of Visual Studio/TFS. You may try to google if this class was moved to another assembly or if there is workaround, maybe you should check where MaxLength was used in your code and remove/change that?