# OData dll version issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

In Package configuration file, I gave version 7.0.0 for OData dll's.

```
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Sometime the bin folder showed me the version 6 of OData dll's, what could be the reason?

[image]

Sometime if I delete the bin folder and recompile again, the version is correct, but sometime it's wrong. Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep on facing the same problem, you can opt for bindingRedirect to a lower verion as in this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092928/assembly-binding-redirect-to-a-lower-version) in your configuration file.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.OData.Core"
                              publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0"
                             newVersion="6.0.4"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```